# WKWebView load local html5 project which use sea.js and avalon

Tags: javascript, ios, html, wkwebview

When I load the local html5 project by WKWebView,it can not works.I use the Safari inspector to check the errors.It lists the errors like this:

```
"XMLHttpRequest cannot load  file:///Users....avalon/avalon.me.html. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP."
```

I have try these way below,but they can not works too.

- When I add the html5 to my app project,I select the "Create folder references" item. And I have try add the html5 files to a bundle.Or copy them to document path.It does't works too.I think it does't the path problem.
- I have try these way to load the html5 files:

  ```
  [self.webview loadHTMLString:appHtml baseURL:baseURL];
  [self.webview loadRequest:request];
  [self.webview loadFileURL:indexurl allowingReadAccessToURL:indexurl];
  ```

If I load the html5 files from the local server,it works success.And I have try a simple html5 project which does't use sea.js and avalon,it works success too.I use UIwebView replace WKWebView,it is OK！

I have search this problem for some solution,but I don't find the answer. Is WKWebView do not support to load the local html,like "file:///Users..."?
Is there some solution for this problem?

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

I see you are trying to load an asset from your local machine (`file:///...`). XHR requests cannot be loaded from local machines. You need to set up a development server/environment to properly test you XHR requests.

Comment: I load the html from localhost server is ok. I have search for this problem,somebody says it's a iOS issue.I don't sure.